# Public API access with OAuth 2.0

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

As a *Resource Owner*, I am able to get a response from a *Protected Resource Server* (here: *Service*) using the *Resource Owner Password Credentials* grant type (aka `password`) via `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate`.

```
 Resource Owner
 (e.g. a Users with a browser)
   +   ^
(1)|   |(6)
   |   |
   |   |    (2)
   v   |    credentials
 +-+---+--+         +--------+
 |        +--------->        |
 | Client |         | OAuth2 |
 |        <---------+ Server |
 +-+---^--+ (3)     |        |
   |   |    token   +--------+
(4)|   |(5)
   |   |
 +-v---+---+
 |         |
 | Service |
 |         |
 +---------+
```

However, this *Protected Resource Server* also provides a public API that I want to access, even without a user login. I think this is a common use case, but seems to be not provided by the `OAuth2RestTemplate` since the `AccessTokenProvicerChain` checks for an `AnonymousAuthenticationToken`:

```
if (auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
    if (!resource.isClientOnly()) {
        throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException(
                "Authentication is required to obtain an access token (anonymous not allowed)");
    }
}
```

Of course, I can exceptionally **use a regular `RestTemplate` to access the public API, but is this the usual way to do it?**

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you use `OAuth2RestTemplate` you should always be authenticated. How could it be, that you are anonymous?

Comment: @dur Thanks for your comment. Let's say the _Protected Resource Server_ provides product images for everyone, but higher resolutions only for logged-in users. A google bot will not use a log in form and will imho get a spring security anonymous session that currently results in a `InsufficientAuthenticationException` instead of getting the lower resolution product image.

Comment: Isn't that a complete different question? Google doesn't use `OAuth2RestTemplate`. However, if you authorize the URLs for anonymous Google will have access. That should not be a problem.

Comment: @dur The `OAuth2RestTemplate` is used in the _Client_ which is, in terms of OAuth 2.0, one of my backend systems. How I should realize anonymous access with Spring Security and OAuth 2.0 is the real question here (see `InsufficientAuthenticationException`)...

Comment: *The OAuth2RestTemplate is used in the Client which is, in terms of OAuth 2.0, one of my backend systems.* That's right. But Google is a different client, doesn't use `OAuth2RestTemplate` . However, if your question is how to unprotect some URL, it is easy (and basic knowledge). You have to `permitAll` the URL. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48632443/5277820

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided for another approach. Anyway, you *can* create a JWT for an "anonymous" session by [disabling the anonymous Spring Security Session](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/122#issuecomment-45451085).

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.anonymous().disable();
}
```

Then, `auth`is not an instance of `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` anymore, but `null`.