# Spring OAuth2 resource classes not getting called

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

In reference to the below questions asked on StackOverflow, I have included a class 
annotated with @Configuration, @EnableResourceServer and @EnableWebSecurity.
The code is building fine but the control is not going in this class which have been annotated the aforementioned way.

[Do I need resource server with Spring Security OAuth2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629266/do-i-need-resource-server-with-spring-security-oauth2)

I checked that Security filters were disabled in my web.xml. Now, I have enabled them. Even though I am not getting the intended result when I hit my request, I think the initial issue is fixed.
That issue got solved but now I am facing another issue: 
HTTP Status 500 - Failed to evaluate expression 'ROLE_USER' 
root cause: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'ROLE_USER' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot' - maybe not public?

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>hk-pensions</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:META-INF/spring/*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
   <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>  
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: please post what you tried so far

Comment: please post your security config class

Comment: Security filters were disabled in my web.xml.
Now, I have enabled them.
Even though I am not getting the intended result when I hit my request, I think the initial issue is fixed.

Comment: nw its working ?

Comment: That issue got solved but now I am facing another issue:
HTTP Status 500 - Failed to evaluate expression 'ROLE_USER'

Comment: root cause</b></p><pre>org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'ROLE_USER' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot' - maybe not public?

Comment: Can @EnableResourceServer work without spring boot application?
I created a demo app using spring boot in which its working fine.
But in my real application, its not working which is not made on Spring boot.